# send keys not working in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have tried to click in the box, clear , and enter text into box but sendkeys don't do anything.I am new to selenium so detailed answer will help. 
This is what I am trying to use as input :

Thanks in Advance !!

```
public void tokensubmit() {
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.className("text-input text-input-md")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.className("text-input text-input-md")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.className("text-input text-input-md")).sendKeys("test");
```

Comment: please provide HTML code

Answer (score 0):

If this is the code you are using it's not working because of an error using `By.className()` with a compound class. You can only use `By.className()` with a single class name but you have used two, "text-input" and "text-input-md" (separated by a space). You should try a CSS selector, e.g.

```
public void tokensubmit()
{
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".text-input.text-input-md"));
    e.click();
    e.clear();
    e.sendKeys("test");
}
```

When you repeatedly use `driver.findElement()`, you are scraping the page each time. Generally you can grab the element and store it and then use that variable for the actions, as I've done above.

Comment: I tried using the same code you gave still the value is not being submitted into the page, no error I got before or now. This is the element I get when i try to inspect and I am using class from here. : <textarea class="text-input text-input-md" aria-labelledby="lbl-2" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="paste token" formcontrolname="newAccessToken" rows="10"></textarea>

Comment: Open the page in Chrome and enter the CSS selector above into the dev console using `$$()`... how many elements does it return? Is the first element the one you are trying to enter text into? Is it inside an IFRAME?

Comment: zero results, will it help if i send the code thts displayed in element window ? like email it you.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? At least post some of the HTML in your question.